# Magento 2.3.0 : Getting error in static content deploy command

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, static-content

I am using Porto and updated Magento from 2.2.5 to 2.3.0 while deploying static content I am facing error that styles-1.css missing in the theme folder.

Comment: check if this file is transfered to 2.3.0 and it's physically exists under target folder.

Comment: Please, share your full error

Comment: @Abdul, someone also faced the similar kind of issue please check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122607/style-m-css-not-found-error-for-custom-theme-in-magento-2

Comment: Fixed by copying style-m.css and style-I.css from default theme to custom theme.
Thank you all.